# Неправильная прорисовка линий SVG path

Tags: html, svg

Стал изучать тег `path` в `svg` пытаюсь сделать такую линию:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что получается:

```html
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 200 32" xml:space="preserve">
       <path d='M0 0 l85 0, 115 32, 200 32' />
</svg>
```

Вроде координаты правильно указываю, но что-то идет не так.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С запятыми была путаница.

- Нужно запятыми разделять два соседних положительных числа, которые
  указывают на координаты `x` `y`, а узловые точки пути разделять
  пробелами.
  (можно запятыми не разделять соседние положительные цифры, а разделить их пробелами, но с запятыми более наглядно).

**Update**
Если в формуле патча  присутствуют команды `L(lineto),` `C(curveTo`), `A(Elliptical Arc)` и другие команды формулы патч, то перед ними не нужно ставить запятые:

`<path d="M0 0 L85 0, 115 32, 200 32 
<path d="M10 10 C20 20, 40 20, 50 10`

О других форматах записи данных `path` можно почитать [здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=897)

- Если не указано `fill="none"` то, по умолчанию устанавливается
  `fill="black"` и весь путь закрашивается сплошным чёрным цветом.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 200 32" style="border:1px solid red;">
 
       <path d="M0,1 90,1 120,31 200,31" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
 
</svg>
```

- Можно с помощью `<polyline>` нарисовать точно такую же ломанную линию

```html
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 200 32" >
 
     <polyline points="0,1 90,1 120,31 200,31" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
 
</svg>
```